# Indentation error: unident doesnt mach any outer dent level, whle executing python selenium webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

```
from Libs.Core.GetConfig import GetConfig
from Libs.Common import Logging
import os
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from HtmlTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class Dummy(GetConfig):

    def __init__(self, namespace=__name__, level="info"):

        super(Dummy, self).__init__(namespace, level)
        self._level = level
        self._namespace = namespace
        self._log = Logging.GetLogger(namespace, self._level)

    def test_ail_login(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver=webdriver.firefox()
        driver.get("www.ultimatix.net")
        self.username1=self.driver.find_element_by_id("USER")
        self.username1.clear()
        self.password1=self.driver.find_element_by_id("PASSWORD")        
        self.password1.clear()
        #title1=self.driver.title()
        #self.assertIn("Ultimatix - Digitally Connected !", driver.title,"both the names of titles are not identicle")
        self.assertTrue(driver.title=="Ultimatix - Digitally Connected !" ,"both titles are not same")
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        self.username1.send_keys("asdfasdfasdfasdf")
        self.password1.send_keys("asdfasdfasdf")
        driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
        driver.close()
```

[image]

error is : at

Comment: Please format your code because it seems to me your indentation is wrong after `class`

Comment: I have created a separate engine to execute this so it doesnt need any class.

Comment: I mean seaprated framework in python ..

Comment: Sorry class also there and other def functions are in perfect indentation..still it is showing me the same error.
I have coded the class like class testname(Getconfig):

Comment: Please format or elaborate, because now I cannot help you. Not enough information

Comment: please find the below answer there i mentioned the full code which throwing the indentation error still is well indented

Comment: Try removing all whitespaces after where the error is thrown and reformat. Sometimes this is an issue with `tabbing`

Answer (score 0):

```
from Libs.Core.GetConfig import GetConfig
from Libs.Common import Logging
import os
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from HtmlTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class Dummy(GetConfig):

    def __init__(self, namespace=__name__, level="info"):

        super(Dummy, self).__init__(namespace, level)
        self._level = level
        self._namespace = namespace
        self._log = Logging.GetLogger(namespace, self._level)

    def test_tcsmail_login(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver=webdriver.firefox()
        driver.get("www.ultimatix.net")
        self.username1=self.driver.find_element_by_id("USER")
        self.username1.clear()
        self.password1=self.driver.find_element_by_id("PASSWORD")        
        self.password1.clear()
        #title1=self.driver.title()
        #self.assertIn("Ultimatix - Digitally Connected !", driver.title,"both the names of titles are not identicle")
        self.assertTrue(driver.title=="Ultimatix - Digitally Connected !" ,"both titles are not same")
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        self.username1.send_keys("dfds")
        self.password1.send_keys("afdssd")
        driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
        driver.close()
```

Comment: it seems like you mixed up spaces and tabs. try to replace all tabs with spaces (or the other way round if you prefer tabs)